# How to set heading accessibility to Toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Toolbar on my android app, and the talkback is reading the title of it. I want the TalkBack to read it with suffix "Heading". I understand this can be done using setHeading function (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#setHeading(kotlin.Boolean). But my app's min sdk is 26 so this API is not suitable. Can anyone please guide me if there is a way to do this without altering the existing title?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```kotlin
val titleTextView = toolbar.children.firstOrNull { view ->
    view is TextView && view.text.toString() == "YOUR_TITLE_HERE"
} as TextView?
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityHeading(titleTextView, true)
```